# Django rest framework serializer key error

Tags: python, django

I was using a standard Django user model but then requirements changed and I had to resort to an abstract user model. I updated my serializer to reflect the changes in model fields as well as form fields but I'm now getting an error when attempting to creating a user object. The error message is `KeyError: 'unl_email'` but also shows up for all the other fields. The `validated_data` for the `create()` function in serializers.py appears to be empty when I `print`. What am I doing wrong?

**Views.py**

```
class SignUp(CreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = SignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response({"success": "Registration succesful"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    unl_num = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unl_usu_num = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null =True)
    unl_date_added = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    unl_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_surname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    unl_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_identity= models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_oss_num= models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_race= models.CharField(max_length=32)
    unl_gender= models.CharField(max_length=32)
    unl_disability= models.CharField(max_length=32)
    unl_location= models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_province= models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unl_avatar= models.CharField(max_length=256)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'unl_email'
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class SignUpSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('unl_email','password','unl_name',
                 'unl_surname','unl_mobile','unl_identity',
                 'unl_oss_num','unl_race','unl_gender','unl_disability',
                 'unl_location','unl_province','unl_avatar'
                 )

        password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            unl_email=validated_data['unl_email'],
            unl_name=validated_data['unl_name'],
            unl_surname=validated_data['unl_surname'],
            unl_mobile=validated_data['unl_mobile'],
            unl_identity=validated_data['unl_identity'],
            unl_oss_num=validated_data['unl_oss_num'],
            unl_race=validated_data['unl_race'],
            unl_gender=validated_data['unl_gender'],
            unl_disability=validated_data['unl_disability'],
            unl_location=validated_data['unl_location'],
            unl_province=validated_data['unl_province'],
            unl_avatar=validated_data['unl_avatar']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: call `serializer.save()` after checking `if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):` else return `serializer.errors` and add the errors in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `serializers.Serializer` and then specifying a model attribute for that serializer, which it does not use. Change it to `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead.